# Access points in iOS 4.0+

Tags: iphone

Since iOS4, Apple has been using their own database for location. Skyhook is still used on prior versions, such as 1.1.3 and 3.1. How is Apple implementing their Access points? Is it possible to submit or contribute to Apple in any way?

We have a locations with lots or reliable hotspots indoors in malls and stores that are not covered in 4.0+ devices.

Comment: This isn't a programming question, but one about Apple's services, so it really isn't a good fit for this site.  Perhaps this would be a better location to ask: http://apple.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems submitting hotspots to Apple's database isn't supported currently, but will be soon according to this [discussion thread](http://discussions.apple.com/message.jspa?messageID=11809168):

> Many people (myself included) noticed
>   that Location Services stopped working
>   with the upgrade to iOS 4.0. The
>   symptom is that Maps and other apps
>   say "Your location could not be
>   determined." even in areas that used
>   to work. The problem is that starting
>   in iOS 3.2 and iOS 4.0, Apple switched
>   from using the SkyHook location
>   database to using their own. Whereas
>   the SkyHook database had the ability
>   for users to add their own WiFi access
>   points, Apple does not have anyway for
>   us to do that.
>
> I just spent over an hour on the phone
>   with Apple Support senior advisors,
>   who initially wanted to restore my
>   unit or even replace it (neither of
>   which would have fixed it), until I
>   found the news reports about Apples
>   new location database. Eventually, I
>   found a senior advisor who was able to
>   track down the problem and admitted
>   that, yes, since the switch from
>   SkyHook to Apple's own database, many
>   WiFi access points no longer work with
>   location services. "Apple is working
>   on the problem, and eventually it will
>   be fixed, although there isn't any
>   time estimate." **I asked specifically
>   if this meant that Apple was going to
>   allow users to add their own WiFi
>   access points, and she said "Yes.**"